# Why doesn't the winter soldier break?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

Yesterday I went to the cinema and watched *Captain America: Civil War*, the movie was great IMO, I have no big complaints.

Although, one of the things that bugged me is how come the Winter Soldier didn't break any of his non-enhanced parts of the body, since he is only shown to have a superhuman arm. Also, when Iron Man gets angry at the end of the movie and destroys his enhanced arm he basically can't do anything any more.

There was no on-screen enhancement with a serum as far as I remember in any of the movies. I understand that he is a trained soldier, perhaps the best one in the world (if you don't count cap); but still if he gets knocked into a wall it shouldn't be so easy to recover from.

So if he gets punched by Iron Man (when he stopped holding back) anywhere but in the arm he should get at least some broken bones. Why doesn't that occur in the movie (apart from the plot armor that kinda saved captain america too in the end since it's his movie)?

Comment: Arnim Zola experimented on him, which presumably included some form of super-serum.

Comment: Relevant: [How long has the Winter Soldier been active?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56318/21267)

Comment: spoilers? Perhaps?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Winter Soldier *is* enhanced

From *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*:

> **Steve Rogers**: Zola. Bucky's whole unit was captured in '43, Zola
>   experimented on 'em. **Whatever he did, it helped Bucky survive the
>   fall. They must have found him.**

The experiments that Hydra conducted presumably included super-serums and similar strength-enhancing mechanisms.

In *Civil War*, Bucky consistently shows the ability to jump implausible distances, and to survive long falls with barely a scratch. He also is able to block bullets with his metal hand, which requires an extraordinarily fast reaction time, as well as great speed.

He is clearly enhanced far above baseline.

Comment: In addition, everyone in the movie is [Made of Iron](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MadeOfIron).